# How do I find where the current value of the option 'registration' in the SQL database?

Tags: multisite

I am trying to understand what the following line from wp-signup.php does:

```
$active_signup = get_site_option( 'registration' );
```

I can see from the following documentation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_site_option
that this will return the value of the site option '`registration`'.

But how do I find where the current value of the option 'registration' in the SQL database?
Or in general, how do I find the association between a key and the data in the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the function `get_site_option()` works a bit differently from `get_option()` on its own. On WordPress Multisite (ie, with Network Mode enabled), there are two different kinds of options:

- site-specific options, which are stored in the individual options tables for each blog (`wp_options`, `wp_5_options`, etc). These options are accessed with `get_option()`, `update_option()`, etc. Note that this assumes that the current blog - the one set in `$wpdb->blog_id` - is the blog from which you want to get the option. You can use `get_blog_option()` etc to get options from the non-current blog.
- network-wide options, which are shared between all sites on a network, and are stored in `wp_sitemeta`. These options are accessed with `get_site_option()`, `update_site_option()`, etc.

(Note that the 'site' terminology is a bit confusing: before WordPress 3.0 and the merge of WPMU, what we now call 'sites' were called 'blogs', and what we now call 'the network' (ie, the entire installation) was called 'the site'. That's why you use `x_site_meta()` to get networkwide stuff.)

If you are running Multisite, then `registration` is stored in `wp_sitemeta`. Thus the use of `get_site_option()`.

If you are *not* running Multisite, there is no `wp_sitemeta` table, and the `_site_option()` functions simply fall back on `_option()`, so that `get_site_option( 'registration' )` will return the value of `get_option( 'registration' )`.

For more on the options functions, see `wp-includes/options.php` https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/option.php (the option.php file was introduced recently into trunk; on a distribution version, look in `wp-includes/functions.php`).

Comment: Thank you for differentiating between get_option and get_site_option. There is precious little documentation on this that I could find. I am going to write a simple plugin to experiment with this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find every options in the table `wp_options`

Regarding the association between a key and the data, if you are referring to the "Custom fields", you must use the [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) functions.

In the db you'll find this keys in the table `wp_postmeta`. To recover a key, you must know the post_id, of course!

Answer (score 1):

`registration` stores whether or not the site is allowing new users to register. It seems like it will either be `none`, `blog`, `user`, or `all`. Some of those seem to be wpmu specific, so  they may not apply to you, depending on your usage case.  I think `registration` is set somewhere in settings, in case you need to change it.

Comment: Yes that is also my understanding, but I was trying to find my way through the PHP code to the SQL database (where does PHP calls the SQL data, and how). Unfortunately I cannot find documentation, and the code is not obvious to me.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking then?